# use of session value in constructor in laravel

Tags: laravel

I am stuck to the use of session value in __constructor but it shows null value. I also add some configuration in kernel.php but still, it is not working. please help.

```
public function __construct()
{
    /** PayPal api context **/
    $this->middleware(function ($request, $next) {
        $paypal_conf = \Config::get('paypal');
        $orgId=Session::get('org_id');
        $org_credentials=PaypalCredentials::where('org_id','=',orgId)->first();
        $credentials=$org->paypalCredentials;
        $this->_api_context = new ApiContext(new OAuthTokenCredential(
            $credentials->client_id,
            $credentials->client_secret));
        $this->_api_context->setConfig($paypal_conf['settings']);  

       return $next($request);
 });


}

protected $middleware = [
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
    \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
    \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
];
```

Comment: We need more info to be able to help. Under normal circumstances, if this is a web route and `org_id` is set, and the session cookie is passed on correctly, your code should work. We can't reasonably know what's wrong in this particular case with the amount of information you supplied. Also **do not start the session in every single route**. Session does not make sense in api routes

Answer (score -1):

```
    public function __construct()
    {
        /** PayPal api context **/
        $this->middleware(function ($request, $next) {
            $paypal_conf = \Config::get('paypal');
            $orgID = $this->getSession('org_id');

            $org_credentials=PaypalCredentials::where('org_id','=',orgId)->first();
            $credentials=$org->paypalCredentials;
            $this->_api_context = new ApiContext(new OAuthTokenCredential(
                $credentials->client_id,
                $credentials->client_secret));
            $this->_api_context->setConfig($paypal_conf['settings']);  

           return $next($request);
     });


    }

private function getSession(){

            return \Session::get('org_id');

}
```